# CMake with protobuf file in subdirectory

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers

I have seen a lot of similar questions and answers, but until now it seems not so obvious to get it working. I am quite new to CMake and until now everything was easy except the integration with protocol buffers.

I have a project with subdirectories, where each subdirectory has its own CMakeLists.txt

One of the subdirectory contains a .proto file. If the PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP macro is executed it generates the sources and the headers files. This macro is invoked from the CMakeLists.txt in the subdirectory containing the .proto file.

It seems however the make file is not invoked because no sources are added to the target. I can not add the sources to the target, because the files do not exist, they exist after generation, so this results in an error when CMake runs.

Setting the file properties to generated seems also not to help. In general, before the build process starts the macro should have been run to generated the source files.

How to do this, any working examples ?

Example:

./src/externals/protodef (from other repository, only contains .proto files)
./src/generated (supposed for the generated c and header files by protoc)

CMakeLists-1 (project root)

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 2.6)
PROJECT (prototest)

ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/externals/protodef")
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY("${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src")

SET_SOURCE_FILES_PROPERTIES(${PROTO_SOURCES} ${PROTO_HEADERS} PROPERTIES GENERATED TRUE)

ADD_EXECUTABLE(prototest ${PROTO_SOURCES} ${SOURCE} )
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(prototest ${EXTERNAL_LIBS} )

SET(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
```

CMakeLists-2 (src)

```
SET(SOURCE ${SOURCE}
  ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp

  PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

CMakeLists-3 (src/externals/protodef)

```
SET(PROTOBUF_PATH "D:/protobuf-3.0.0/" )
SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} "${PROTOBUF_PATH}")

# Changing PROTO_SRCS and PROTO_HDRS does not work for setting the location 
# of the generated files.
# Those variable are ignored by CMake for compiling the proto files.
# Using a dedicated CMakeLists.txt and settng CURRENT_BINARY dir is a 
# workaround to get them where we want.
SET(GENERATED_DIR ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/generated )
SET(CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR ${GENERATED_DIR} )


INCLUDE(FindProtobuf)
FIND_PACKAGE(Protobuf REQUIRED)

PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/test1.proto)

SET( EXTERNAL_LIBS ${PROTOBUF_PATH}/lib/libprotobuf.a PARENT_SCOPE)

# Propagate sources to the parant project
SET(PROTO_SOURCES ${PROTO_SRCS}
PARENT_SCOPE
)

SET(PROTO_HEADERS ${PROTO_HDRS}
PARENT_SCOPE
)
```

Comment: please post a [mcve]

Comment: you have to mark the generated .h and .cpp files with the GENERATED property, so that cmake knows that they will exist when it comes time to make them.

Comment: @Richard I tried setting the GENERATED property. It seems that the only thing it does is filling in the filenames of the files "to be generated" into the variables passed to the macro. But in this case the files still do not exist and adding the variable to the project sources files then result in a cmake error, because it contains the name of a non existing file.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First generate the protobuf files, then add them to a CMake target.

CMakeLists (src) :

```
# Generate h/cpp proto files (./src/externals/protodef) into ./src/generated folder
PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP(...)

# Process subdir
ADD_SUBDIRECTORY(generated)
```

It seems that `PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP` can only be used in the same subdirectory. A possible workaround is to invoke protoc directly instead :

```
 FILE(TO_NATIVE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/externals/protodef PROTOMODEL_PATH)
 FILE(TO_NATIVE_PATH ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/generated PROTOBINDING_PATH)

 FILE(GLOB DATAMODEL_PROTOS "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/externals/protodef/*.proto")

 FOREACH(proto ${DATAMODEL_PROTOS})
    FILE(TO_NATIVE_PATH ${proto} proto_native)
    EXECUTE_PROCESS(COMMAND ${PROTOBUF_PROTOC_EXECUTABLE} --proto_path=${PROTOMODEL_PATH} --cpp_out=${PROTOBINDING_PATH} ${proto_native}
    RESULT_VARIABLE rv)
    # Optional, but that can show the user if something have gone wrong with the proto generation 
    IF(${rv})
         MESSAGE("Generation of data model returned ${rv} for proto ${proto_native}")
    ENDIF()
 ENDFOREACH(proto)
```

CMakeLists (src/generated) :

```
## List generated sources files
FILE(GLOB HDRS "*.h")
FILE(GLOB SRCS "*.cc")

ADD_LIBRARY(protoBinding ${HDRS} ${SRCS})
# ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES} should be defined by FIND_PACKAGE(Protobuf REQUIRED)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(protoBinding ${PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES})
```

This way CMake will first generate the header/source files, and only then add the generated files to a CMake target.

You can then use `protoBinding` target to link the generated files to an other target (e.g at the end of `src`'s CMakeLists.txt) :

```
ADD_LIBRARY(myModel ${myFiles})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myModel protoBinding)
```

Comment: I used the second option which gives a bit more control. It works like a charm. 
In my case PROTOBUF_LIBRARIES points to libprotobuf.dll.a
I want to link libprotobuf statically as Google advises. Currently I set the lib manually, probably there is a cleaner way.

Comment: There should be a way to add multiple `PROTO_PATH` in `PROTOBUF_GENERATE_CPP`. For now, `EXECUTE_COMMAND` is a decent workaround. I don't like the idea of doing `GLOB`  , so I implemented a loop and stored all the .h and .cc files in a variable. Thanks anyway!